# Combination of FromDigits and ConstantArray gives strange result

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to concatenate the integers contained within my `Array` in order to form a single integer. For this, I am using a combination of `FromDigits` and  `ConstantArray`. However, I am getting an unexpected result. The following code gives a minimal working example of my problem:

```
FromDigits[ConstantArray[123, 2]]
```

which results in:

```
1353
```

instead of the expected:

```
123123
```

Reading the Mathematica documentation, [ConstantArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) "*generates a list of n copies of the element c*", while [FromDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html) "*constructs an integer from the list of its decimal digits*". To me it seems like the result should be `123123`, but for some reason I get the strage output above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `FromDigits[StringJoin[ToString /@ ConstantArray[123, 2]]]`?

Comment: The base of `FromDigits` defaults to 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting ref/FromDigits/Scope/#2:

> Digits larger than the base are "carried"

So `FromDigits[{123,123}]` is like `FromDigits[{1, 2 + 1, 3 + 2, 3}]`

For your problem:

```
FromDigits @ Flatten @ IntegerDigits @ ConstantArray[123, 2]
```

> ```
> 123123
> ```

Comment: Or `FromDigits[Flatten @ ConstantArray[IntegerDigits @ 123, 2]]`